# Flash Player in Google Chrome does not work on Ubuntu Live CD

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, flash

I use Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTE Live CD.

I tried to install Google Chrome using terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

It got some problems while installing, but solved it using:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And after that I run the Google chrome installation again.

It worked, and I am able to start Google Chrome.

Then, it always happens that Ubuntu ask me to set a new password for "keyring". I ignored that, and Ubuntu said it has found an internal problem.

After all these things, I tried to run Flash Player on Google Chrome, but it said: download failed.

In the past, it did not happened. It only started happening this week.

I tried `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` but it said `Unable to locate package flashplugin-installer`.

I tried deleting `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash` but it also didn't work.

What should I do? I just want to run flash.

Comment: Google Chrome comes with Flash built-in; you don't need to install anything but Google Chrome to use Flash in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're installing wrong package. Chrome uses it's own flash. It's called PepperFlash.

Do not delete `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash`
Or install PepperFlash by editing `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and adding this lines:

`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu your_ubuntu_version multiverse
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu your_ubuntu_version multiverse`

Do not forget to `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`
and install package `apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`

Comment: I cannot do `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: When I use  `apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`, it said Unable to locate package pepperflashplugin-nonfree.

Comment: Then you did something wrong, pepperflashplugin-nonfree is located in http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/pepperflashplugin-nonfree